# File with comma in filename is downloading in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to download a file with the name **10003747,  sa-2019-4-5.pdf**.
It is downloading in Firefox, but throwing an error in Chrome.

Comment: How are you "downloading" it?

Comment: and what is the error thrown?